# Retrieve check in time of employee using SQL by grouping method

Tags: sql

Here I have a Leave table with column of AttendanceId(PK, incremental), EmpId, Check_In_Time, Check_Out_Time, Date. Every-time an employee check in and out the time will be saved in Datetime format. Now I want to get the first "Check_In_Time" of each employee on each day. I tried some grouping in SQL but it went wrong. Any suggestion?

Comment: What version of SQL?  MS SQL Server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
select EmpId, Date, min(Check_In_Time) as Expr1
from Leave
WHERE EmpId = @EmpId
group by EmpId, Date
```

Using the keyword "Date" as a column name is bad practice, by the way.

Comment: Thanks. This answered well my question. I later enhance it to get the time by EmpId as below,
SELECT        EmpId, Expr1
FROM            (SELECT        EmpId, Date, MIN(Time_In) AS Expr1
                          FROM            tblLeave
                          GROUP BY EmpId, Date) AS derivedtbl_1
WHERE        (EmpId = @EmpId)
Sorry to ask. I have another question or doubt deriving from here, should I do a new post or ask it here?

Comment: @Memoc: You don't need the sub-query - see the amended answer.

Comment: Let say I add another column named LossTime in Leave table. I retrieve the first check in time by day according to EmpId using above query. How do also I show LossTime for each of this EmpId.?

Comment: Which value of LossTime - largest, smallest, total...?

Comment: No group value of LossTime.. I just want any Losstime value on same rows of the table produce from query above according to EmpId.

Comment: If any value will do, use min(LossTime) or max(LossTime).

Answer (score 0):

select min(Check_In_Time), DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE())) as date, empId from Leave group by empId, DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, GETDATE()))

Comment: I just realised - see my update - also I didn't see the "Date" column. The DateAdd is a way of extracting the date from a datetime